# Can 2013 retina MacBook Pro (Mavericks) offer same native 1600x1200 via VGA display that worked with 2009 MBP (pre-Mavericks)?

Tags: display, macbook-pro, displayport, vga-adapter

I have a Samsung 213T LCD, with a native resolution of 1600x1200, that worked great as an external monitor, using a DisplayPort VGA adapter, with my 2009 13" MacBook Pro through several OSX releases.

I recently upgraded to a 2013 15" rMBP with Mavericks... and it can't properly detect the monitor, and never shows 1600x1200 as a resolution option.

Things I've tried that haven't helped:

- the 'detect displays' button that appears when holding [option] in 'system-preferences' -> 'display'
- holding [option] when choosing the 'scaled' radio button (it shows more resolution options - but still not the 1600x1200 native)
- resetting PRAM/NVRAM
- both off-brand (monoprice) and Apple VGA DisplayPort adapters
- changing the built-in retina display resolution (to perhaps free video memory)
- the free 'Display Menu' app in the Mac App Store

None have helped.

I wasn't expecting a regression in the ability to drive modest external monitors in the 2015 MBP/Mavericks.

Is there any way to restore this previously-reliable external-display function to my latest & greatest Mac?

Comment: Since you've already tried two VGA adapters, have you thought about giving a thunderbolt to DVI adapter a try? Looks like they aren't extremely expensive on Amazon.

Comment: I'll surely get there, or a HDMI->DVI cord... but this feels like a software glitch with a software fix, just convincing the MBP to output a 1600x1200 signal.